# using TEMLATEPATH (of wordpress) in JS

Tags: javascript, wordpress, http

I use wordpress and I wanted to ask, is there a way to use the TEMPLATEPATH in my JS.
Like this:

```
jQuery ("#​​ajax").load ("<?php echo TEMPLATEPATH;?>" + "/aaa.txt");
```

The problem is the result of TEMPLATEPATH is C:\XAMPP\HTDOCS ... And therefore i have browser error: Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a great deal of information provided. Are you using Wordpress on `localhost`? With a `file://` protocol?

Anyway, try replacing `TEMPLATEPATH` with `get_template_directory_uri()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP to print a JavaScript variable with the templatepath.

Or the other option is to print this JavaScript code using PHP itself.

Comment: the problem was, that temlatepath give me c:\... instead of the write URL that is localhost...